# What about an alternative formulation for different prime constellations in the spirit of Suzuki's theorem for twin primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-constellations

It is known that the twin prime conjecture is a special case of the $k$-tuple conjecture. See if you want the article with title *k-Tuple Conjecture* from the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld.

On the other hand I know* the **Theorem 2** of [1], due to Suzuki, concerning a formulation of the twin prime problem.

> **Question.** Is it possible/feasible to get an alternative formulation, in the spirit of Suzuki's Theorem 2, for different prime constellations/k-tuples? **Many thanks.**

If the statement is in the literature refer the bibliography, and I try to read it from the literature.

### References:

[1] Maria Suzuki, *Alternative Formulations of the Twin Prime Problem*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 107, No. 1 (January, 2000).

Comment: *Few months ago I've read it as a free article view from My JSTOR account

Comment: stating suzuki's result briefly would improve this question

Comment: Many thanks for all comments.

Comment: Also I add that the online encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld has an article entitled  *Prime Constellation*